# Web / Browser push notification from web to mobile device (cross platform) using azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have a website which is hosted on Azure. I would like to "Web push notification" or "Browser push notification" from web to all mobile device (cross platforms). I don't have a mobile app, just a website. So what I want is if a customer agrees to allow notifications on his device then it should show on it even while device is locked.

This website described full functional view of requirement: https://www1.vizury.com/web-push-notifications-defined

But this is paid service and I have already azure subscription so i would like to use azure notification hub and want to build this functionality.
**Application : Asp.net MVC + Azure Hosting** ,
**Requirement: notification from web browser to mobile device without mobile app, if possible using azure notification hub**

If any one know about this type of requirement solution please provide me a way to implement it.

Comment: I think you have to create some custom application for the same. You can use RabbitMq which is open source to achieve this feature. You can also use other Publisher/Subscriber frameworks. The link provided by you uses Service worker which is available for almost most of the popular browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are several techniques that do the job, I would suggest Web Sockets as it turned out to be the most performant solution, at least in my case.

There's also a framework for ASP.NET called SignalR that transparently encapsulates some of the most common techniques like Web Sockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Long Polling, so that you don't have to deal with fallback mechanisms yourself. Have a look here: https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: SignalR will work for browser to browser only, My requirement is like if i close the browser in mobile device(android/ios/windows) or desktop then also msg should appear on as notification even though device locked. please visit this website you will understand https://www1.vizury.com/web-push-notifications-defined

Comment: I think you can't do that with a pure HTML5 frontend... you can never control the user's browser. SignalR is full duplex, by the way, we use it in many scenarios for Server --> HTML5 frontend notification and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Robert for reply but I think you are not getting my point, i would like to get notification on mobile device (same as like facebook, what'sup, SMS on top of our mobile screen) without installing any app. and when we click on notification then it will redirect to website in mobile browser.